# Convert list into two dimensional array of objects in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

i have a list like this:

```
list<Box*> list;
```

where Box is an object that contains a value for x and y.

```
box->getX();
box->getY();
```

What i need to do is convert it into a two dimensional array (or a vector of vectors), where:

```
array[x][y] == box;
```

I also need to have empty or null object into this array, i.e.: Position 4,6 has nothing (or an empty object).

My idea:

```
Box** boxes = new Box*[rows];
    for(int r=0;r<rows;r++)
        boxes[r] = new Box[columns];


    for(Box *b : list){
        boxes[b->x][b->y] = b;
    }
```

But this give me an error: No viable overloaded =;

Another point: I need to have the same pointer as the list, not a copy of those items.

Comment: `or a vector of vectors`  Preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b` is a `Box*`, but because `boxes` is a `Box**`, `boxes[b->x][b-y]` is just a `Box`. So you have a type mismatch - you're trying to assign a `Box*` to a `Box`, hence the error.

If you want to make `boxes` a 2d array of `Box*`, you just need another `*`:

```
Box*** boxes = new Box**[rows];
for(int r=0;r<rows;r++) {
    boxes[r] = new Box*[columns];
}
```

Now this will work:

```
for (Box *b : list){
    boxes[b->x][b->y] = b;
}
```

Comment: This assumes x and y are indexes and not coordinates.  If coordinates, think of what happens when there are a few boxes in a large coordinate space.  That is a lot of wasted array indexes.  I would probably use a `std::map` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's assuming a lot of context not present in the problem. I'm simply addressing the type issue.

Comment: Well, assuming a lot of things, you nailed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the vector of vectors:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>

struct Box 
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

typedef std::vector<Box*> BoxVector;
typedef std::vector<BoxVector> BoxVector2D;

int main()
{
    std::list<Box*> lBoxes;
    BoxVector2D boxes;

    // fill lBoxes as needed...

    for(Box *b : lBoxes)
    {
        boxes.resize(b->x+1);
        boxes[b->x].resize(b->y + 1);
        boxes[b->x][b->y] = b;
    }

    // use boxes as needed...
}
```

Now, as the other comments suggested, I'm assuming that the coordinate space is reasonable.  Note that we `resize` the vector for each item, ensuring we don't go out of bounds.

As to the `resize` -- the `vector::resize` is basically a no-op if the capacity is greater than the resize amount.  Therefore the `resize` only does work if either `b->x + 1` or `b->y + 1` exceeds the current vector's capacity.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `x` and `y` are coordinates where the `Box` is located within a given coordinate space.  If that is the case, they are not really suitable for array/vector indexes.  You would have to allocate the array/vector to account for all possible coordinates, even ones that do not contain a `Box`.  As such, I would suggest using a `std::map` instead, eg:

```
std::list<Box*> BoxList; 
std::map<int, std::map<int, Box*> > BoxMap;

...

for (std::list<Box*>::iterator iter = BoxList.begin(); iter != BoxList.end(); ++iter)
{
    Box *box = *iter;
    BoxMap[box->getX()][box->getY()] = box;
}
```

You still get the benefit of the `array[x][y]` syntax you want, but you use much less memory (proportional to the actual number of `Box` objects you have), and if you try to access a `Box` at a given x/y coordinate where no `Box` exists, you will get back a NULL pointer that you can test for:

```
Box *box = BoxMap[x][y];
if (box) ...
```